# Einstein Bot Reading Cookie Into Chat Context

Tags: einstein, snap-ins, bots

I've been searching for a solution through either Apex or Configuration that would allow my Einstein Bot to read a cookie on the page that my snap-in is deployed onto.

For example, when the Chat Bot is opened, it reads the value of a cookie set on the page `userType=Partner` and then performs conditional logic to display a certain set of menu items for that user.

Is there any possible way to achieve this with the current release of Einstein Bots? If not, is there any workaround were a page can pass a parametric value directly into the snap-in so that it can be exposed to the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into collecting pre-chat information in this Einstein bot cookbook. It's not a cakewalk and will probably require a lot of trial and error but this is the way to do what you are looking for:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_optimize_flow_lex.htm

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve passing in data to the Transcript object by leveraging the `embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails` setting on the embedded service snippet code.